# Replace part of link pulled from external div

Tags: php, url, str-replace

I have the following code to extract content of an external div and display on my webpage:

First som style to make first letter uppercase in the output-link:

```
<style>
h1:first-letter {text-transform: uppercase;} /* make first letter in link upper-case */
h1 {margin-bottom: -15px; font-size:1.2em;}
p {margin-bottom: 5px;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
</style>
```

Then the php code (*edited with final changes based on @Bang's answer*):

```
<?php   
    //The URL for the external content we want to pull
    $url = 'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);

    //The div that includes the content '<div id="divid">'
    $first_step = explode( '<div id="ide">' , $content );
    $second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

    //Do some magic with the URL
    $url2 = $second_step[0];

    //What do you want to replace?
    $patterns = array(
        '#\./opening;jsessionid=.*\?#',
        '#<a href=#',
        '#span(.*?)>#'
    );

    //...with what?
    $replaces = array(
        'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening?',
        '<a target="_blank" href=',
        'h1>'
    );

    //Print the final output
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $url2), $second_step[1], $second_step[2], $second_step[3], $second_step[4], $second_step[5], $second_step[6], '<hr>';
?>
```

This code pulls a link in the `$second_step[0]` on the last line. This link is formatted like this: `.opening\and_following_dynamic_link_text`.

I try to use `str_replace`to alter the url to remove `.opening` and add the original host followed by `/opening`.

I have tried to insert the `str_replace` string after `$first_step`and `$second_step`, and as you can see in the code after `$content`.
But I just can't get this to work.

Can someone help me solving this?
Also, the final output includes some special chars that displays like `Ã¸`. How can I get this to display as the original character?

For an example look [HERE](http://tangeland.net/test/).

***EDIT:** Thanks @kadam-sunil and @bank, both your answers helped me here. I updated the code with the working solution!*

I've also managed to remove some unwanted text in the URL, ref my comments to @bang's answer.

Now I'm trying to insert a target="_blank" into the URL I've extracted. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

***EDIT2:** Here's the raw data I'm trying to display*

```
  <div id="ide">
        <div>
            <div class="openingTitle"><a href="./opening;jsessionid=E2A19018E967B4771224A9FA515AFBC0?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details"><span style="font-weight:bold;">fagarbeider</span></a></div>
            <div class="openingIngress"><p>Avdeling teknisk drift har ledig stilling som fagarbeider vann/avløp.<br/>Fast, 100 %, ledig snarest.</p></div>
            <div class="openingDetail"><i>Utlyst:&nbsp;<span>28.01.2015</span></i></div>
            <div class="openingDetail"><i>Søknadsfrist:&nbsp;<span style="color:red">01.03.2015</span></i></div>
            <div class="openingDetail"><i>Selskap:&nbsp;<span>Randaberg kommune</span></i></div>
            <div class="openingDetail"><i>Stillingstype:&nbsp;<span>Fast ansatt</span></i></div>
            <div class="openingDetail"><i>Lokasjon:&nbsp;<span>Avd. teknisk drift</span></i></div>
            <div class="openingDetail">

            </div>
        </div>
```

I've also edited the original code to reflect the latest changes I've made.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should affect `str_replace` :

```
$content = str_replace('./opening', 'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening', $content);
```

With preg_replace method :

```
$url = '<a href="./opening;jsessionid=E2A19018E967B4771224A9FA515AFBC0?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details"><span style="font-weight:bold;">fagarbeider</span></a>';

// What do you want to replace ?
$patterns = array(
    '#\./opening;jsessionid=.*\?#',
    '#<a href=#',
    '#span(.*?)>#'
);

// By What ?
$replaces = array(
    'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening?',
    '<a target="_blank" href=',
    'h1>'
);

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $url);
```

Then I get `<a target="_blank" href="https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details"><h1>fagarbeider</h1></a>`

And I keep the code simple and stupid.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! But then a new problem presented itself.
It seems that the url pulled from the original page includes a `jsessionid`string that I need to remove for this to work perfectly.

The url pulled after `str-replace` is added: `https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening;jsessionid=48311227429D90F89603CFA1D3EF3859?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details`
What I need it to be: `https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details`

Comment: It there an effective way to fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show me your raw data ($content from file_get_contents) and the raw output you need ? I think there is a more elegant way to reach  the wanted result, just by using preg_replace.

Comment: Thank you @bang, I've edited the code in the original post, and added the raw-rata. I thing I go't the it to work like I want, but if it can be optimized, that would be perfect.

Comment: Thanks, that also worked great, I've edited the original post with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$content1=str_replace('./opening', 'https://ekstern.vuq.visma.com/ra_recruitment/opening', $content);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="ide">' ,  $content1 );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0], $second_step[1], $second_step[2], $second_step[3], $second_step[4], $second_step[5], $second_step[6];
?>
```